# Mantis BT 1.2.5 / Export XML isn't working

Tags: mantis

We've been running a Mantis 1.1.8 install for some time. Recently, we had a need to export a project. As such, I upgraded to 1.2.5 following the instructions here: http://www.mantisbt.org/manual/manual.installation.upgrading.php

Now, I'm trying to export the project as XML from the View Issues page. I've got about 100 issues to export (for this test), and Export XML is returning a blank XML document. Exporting as a CSV is working fine.  Any ideas why this is?

I've tried a number of different variants, with no success.

Comment: So ... partially answering my own question.I looked in the Apache log, and noticed the following error. This is just a PHP configuration error. I'm not sure how common this is.<br>
[Thu May 05 16:03:08 2011] [error] [client 192.150.10.200] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XMLWriter' not found in /data/www/html/mantisbt-1.2.5/plugins/XmlImportExport/pages/export.php on line 56, referer: http://xdce.adobe.com/mantisbt-1.2.5/view_all_bug_page.php

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is still an issue after all this time, note that I recently committed several improvements to the XML import/export plugin. I suggest you download a [nightly build](http://www.mantisbt.org/builds/) and check if the export works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [installing XML support for PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xmlwriter.requirements.php) first.